# How do I get the MIME Type from a URI with scheme == "android.resource"

Tags: android

I know how to get the MIME Type from an URI when the scheme is "content" or "file". However, I cannot find any solution when the scheme is "android.resource". For example, I have `res/raw/video.mp4`.

```
val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$packageName/${R.raw.video}")
```

The uri is good because I can do the following

```
videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
videoView.start()
```

Given such an URI, how can I get its mime type (should be "video/mp4" in this case)?

Comment: I do not think that is possible, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever) for media file:

```
val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://$context.packageName/${R.raw.video}")
val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
val mimeType = try {
            retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
Log.d(TAG, "MIME type: $mimeType")
```

For any other type:

```
val resId = R.raw.video
val resUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://${context.packageName}/$resId")

val mimeType = tryGetMediaMimetype(context, resUri)
        ?: tryGetImageMimetype(context.resources, resId)
        ?: tryGetMimeTypeFromExtension(context.resources, resId)
Log.d(TAG, "MIME type: $mimeType")

...

fun tryGetMediaMimetype(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
    return try {
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
        retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_MIMETYPE)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
}

fun tryGetImageMimetype(resource: Resources, resId: Int): String? {
    val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    return try {
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resource, resId, options)
        options.outMimeType
    } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
        return null
    }
}

fun tryGetMimeTypeFromExtension(resource: Resources, resId: Int): String? {
    val value = TypedValue()
    resource.getValue(resId, value, true)
    val fileName = value.string.toString()

    val dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".")
    val extension = if (dotIndex >= 0) {
        fileName.substring(dotIndex + 1)
    } else null

    return if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
    } else null
}
```